# Multiply different size nested array with scalar

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, nested

In my python code, I have an array that has different size inside like this

```
arr = [
    [1],
    [2,3], 
    [4],
    [5,6,7],
    [8],
    [9,10,11]
]
```

I want to multiply them by 10 so it will be like this

```
arr = [
        [10],
        [20,30], 
        [40],
        [50,60,70],
        [80],
        [90,100,110]
    ]
```

I have tried `arr = np.multiply(arr,10)` and `arr = np.array(arr)*10`

it seems that both are not working for different size of nested array because when I tried using same size nested array, they actually works just fine

Comment: `arr` is a nested listed for a numpy array?

Comment: `[[i*10 for i in sublist] for sublist in arr]` without numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best to just use a nested loop :

```
arr = [
    [1],
    [2,3], 
    [4],
    [5,6,7],
    [8],
    [9,10,11]
]

def matrix_multiply_all(matrix,nb):
    return list(map(lambda arr : list(map(lambda el : el*nb,arr)),matrix))
print(matrix_multiply_all(arr,10))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with list comprehension as sahasrara62 mentioned if it is a list:

```
[[i*10 for i in x] for x in arr]
```